# What could i do in order to delete/ unistall plugin of my elearning moodle site? Forbiden message

Tags: plugins, moodle

What could I do in order to delete/ unistall plugin of my elearning moodle site?

I get this message when i try it..
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /admin/plugins.php on this server.

[image: Administrator menu]

Comment: You are connected with the admin account to access to yourmoodle.tld/admin/plugins.php ?

Comment: Yes I connect with the admin account!

Comment: If you can access to your webserver with ssh, you can post the owner and the rights of the admin to check that it is not an ownership probelm